# Working with PHP variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

what I am trying to do is the following.
In the URL, only one variable may be present at a time:

```
$search_query = $_GET['user_query'];
          $search_query2 = $_GET['crs_category'];
```

so what I want to do is the following.

If user_query is the one present in the url, than the following line is executed

```
 $get_cats = "select * from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";

    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                        $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

        $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

        $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];




        echo "<a href='searchPage.php?cat=$crs_sub1' id='liSpacing'><label id='labelSearch'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='value'>&nbsp;$crs_sub1</label></a> <br />";



    }
```

However, if its the crs_category variable that is present in the url, than the following gets executed:

```
$get_cats = "select * from category where (category_title like '%$search_query2%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";
            $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                        $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

        $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

        $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];




        echo "<a href='searchPage.php?cat=$crs_sub1' id='liSpacing'><label id='labelSearch'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='value'>&nbsp;$crs_sub1</label></a> <br />";



    }
```

The problem is as follow only user_query or crs_category will be displayed in the URL at once, not both, and hence I receive an error for the one that is displayed. What I want to do is if that url variable is equal to this, grab those information, or if this url variable is equal to that grab those items.w

on another note, I would also like to do the following
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `if(isset($search_query))` and `if(isset($search_query2))` ?

Comment: Use an `if` statement. This is basic PHP (and programming).

Comment: So you're basically looking for [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) ?

Comment: Yeah I believe an isset is what I was looking for. I was thinking of a more complication solution but that could solve it

Comment: Why is it tagged with `jquery`?

Comment: typo, that it was type with jquer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want...

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['user_query']))
    {
$search_query = $_GET['user_query'];
        $get_cats = "select * from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";

            $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

            while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                        $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                                $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

                $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

                $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];




                echo "<a href='searchPage.php?cat=$crs_sub1' id='liSpacing'><label id='labelSearch'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='value'>&nbsp;$crs_sub1</label></a> <br />";



            }
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['crs_category']))
    {
          $search_query2 = $_GET['crs_category'];
        $get_cats = "select * from category where (category_title like '%$search_query2%' )  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";
                    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

            while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
                $crs_sub1 = $row_cats['course_subc1'];
                        $crs_sub2 = $row_cats['course_subc2'];
                                $crs_sub3 = $row_cats['course_subc3'];

                $crs_sub4 = $row_cats['course_subc4'];

                $crs_sub5 = $row_cats['course_subc5'];




                echo "<a href='searchPage.php?cat=$crs_sub1' id='liSpacing'><label id='labelSearch'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='value'>&nbsp;$crs_sub1</label></a> <br />";



            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. my concern with that is that if when crs_category I get an error that $search_query cant be found on the top of your code it seems like your looking for both before calling the if statement

Comment: You are right. Ther for you should use `$search_query = isset($_GET['user_query'])?$_GET['user_query']:null;`

Comment: @JonathanEtienne I changed it to directly check $_GET in the if statements